# Edge optimized API gateway - CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

If we select edge-optimized API endpoint while creation the API gateway, will cloudfront distribution be added/attached internally? Or should we create new distribution and attach it to API gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on the official AWS link.

If your API clients are geographically dispersed, consider using an edge-optimized API endpoint in API Gateway. This type of endpoint acts as a Regional endpoint with an **AWS managed CloudFront web distribution** to improve client connection time.

To use the global CloudFront content delivery network and maintain more control over the distribution, use a Regional API with a custom CloudFront web distribution.